# Cloud Build cannot trigger from GitLab EE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I would like to create a Cloud Build trigger with GitLab Enterprise Edition (EE).

The GitLab EE is 14.10.x. The personal access token has `api`, `read_api` and `read_repository` scopes.

The "connect host" and "connect repository" work well. After creating a trigger, whether the trigger is invoked from pushing to a branch or run by manually, it cannot execute normally.

**Push to a branch:**

> Your build failed to run: Invalid GitLab repo url: cannot find correct string submatch

[image]

**Run manually**

> Failed to trigger build: Couldn't read commit

[image]

The `cloudbuild.yaml` looks like:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:latest'
    args:
      - '--cache=true'
      - '--dockerfile=docker/alpine/Dockerfile'
      - '--destination=asia-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/asia.gcr.io/${_ARTIFACT_REGISTRY}/xxx-api:${TAG_NAME}'
      - '--target=xxx-api'
      - '--context=dir://.'
substitutions:
  _ARTIFACT_REGISTRY: xxx-api-dev
```